# The Listbox items initialize but once one is selected I don't know how to RESET the listbox where neither item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

If you run the code neither of the list box items are selected.  If you select either it remains selected okay and displays either "One" or "Two" in the text box accordingly.  When the ResetListBox button is clicked the selected item is deselected (?maybe) but retains a grey background (undesired).  Once the item has this light grey background the onClick event no longer fires... No additional text is added to the text box.  This question has been asked in various forms all over the web and none of the answers that I've tried in this simple example has worked.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="279.186" Width="401.98">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-6.8,-2.4">
        <ListBox x:Name="ThanklessListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="89" Margin="24,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117">
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ItemI" Content="ItemUno" Selected="ItemI_Selected"/>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="Item2" Content="ItemDos" Selected="Item2_Selected"/>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="StuffToShow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="178" Margin="198,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116"/>
        <Button x:Name="ResetListBox" Content="ResetListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="28,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Click="ResetListBox_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="SeleectButton" Content="SelectItemDos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="28,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Click="SeleectButton_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ItemI_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StuffToShow.Text += "\nOne";
        }

        private void Item2_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StuffToShow.Text += "\nTwo";
        }

        private void SeleectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThanklessListBox.SelectedItem = 1; //Choose Dos
        }

        private void ResetListBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThanklessListBox.SelectedItem = -1; //Deselect
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code behind, you are using SelectedItem with an integer.

```
    private void ResetListBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThanklessListBox.SelectedItem = -1; //Deselect
    }
```

Try either using SelectedIndex

```
    private void ResetListBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThanklessListBox.SelectedIndex = -1; //Deselect
    }
```

Or Selected Item with null

Edited to add: You could also do

```
ThanklessListBox.SelectedItems.Clear
```

which is what I think the other person whose post is now deleted meant>

In fairness, this is something you could really learn just by browsing the [online documentation for ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=net-5.0) on the MS site

Comment: Neither response answers the question, but thanks for the effort.  The use of ThanklessListBox.Clear(); produces the exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can only change SelectedItems collection in multiple selection modes. Use SelectedItem in single select modes.'  Yeah, I already tried that and many other attekmpts... all failed.  One attempt I havent tried yet is to delete every ListBoxItem and reload them but I'm sure to run into a dead end in that effort as well.  I would like to know a solution that was tested successfully.  That would be greatly appreciagted.

Comment: When I took your code and changed it to use `SelectedIndex = -1` instead of `SelectedItem = -1` it worked just fine.  Unless I've misunderstood what you want to do.

Comment: Sincere apologies.  My bad.  The closeness of the two "Index" & "Item" threw me off.  I am so happy to have this working and can't thank you enough.   BTW, I tried deleting and  adding the item back and that worked, but of course that is not how it was intended to be done.

Comment: HI again.  I now realize why I am having endless trouble.  In my actual app I am trying to clear the listitem selection as you pointed out but inside the selected event code rather than a separate button event as I created in my sample.  In the event thread that command will not work.  I'm sorry for misfiring in my question and I'm still stuck.  I'm going to create actually try doing the item delete and add it back to see if that works.

Comment: You know if's a lot easier to use MVVM in this case.  Set your view's `DataContext` property to point to some an object that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.  Give that object a "SelectedItem" property.  In XAML, bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property  to the SelectedItem property in your data context.  Then if you want to clear out the SelectedItem, you just set it to null  In the DataContext,

Comment: Thank you for providing this additional advice.  That is very kind of you.